# How to set Session in spring framewok

Tags: spring, servlets

Now I have a login code like this,UserInfo is a form with username and password

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/loginCheck", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> loginCheck(UserInfo userInfo)

@RequestMapping(value = "/login/PageA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> PageA(){
   //maybe check the session
   //if session expired ,then redirect to login page 
}
```

After login, I should redirect page to Page A, and record the username in session, So in spring framework, Do I just configure it or get Session from request ?

Hope to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, one is to simply inject HttpSession into your handler method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login/PageA", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> PageA(HttpSession httpSession){
   //maybe check the session
   //if session expired ,then redirect to login page 
}
```

The `getAttribute` method of HttpSession will throw IllegalStateException if session is no longer valid, but I have a feeling Spring MVC will create a new session for you when that happen, so also check for non-existence (null value)

Also have a look at the usage of `@SessionAttributes` and `@ModelAttribute` annotation on Spring doc, and Spring Security framework